# How To Get PostFields Of CURL When Someone Use POST CURL Into My API

Tags: php, curl

So, I want to get key value of JSON Data (From POSTFIELD)
Here My Curl Post To Test

```php
<?php
$u = "asd";
$p = "asd";
$tokens = "asd";
$fields_string = '{ "cvalue":"' . $u . '", "ctype":"username", "password":"' . $p . '", "captchaToken":"' . $tokens . '", "captchaId":"", "captchaProvider":"PROVIDER_ARKOSE_LABS" }';

$ch2 = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www-robloxa.com/dd.php');
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
$headers[] = 'Accept: application/json';
$headers[] =   'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36';
$headers[] =    'Referer: https://www.roblox.com/login';
$headers[] = 'Origin: https://www.roblox.com';
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$output = curl_exec($ch2);
echo $output;
?>
```

and here my php api, when i am trying to get the value of the json

```php
<?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

echo $_POST['cvalue']

?>
```

Comment: try `echo json_encode($output)`;

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Receive JSON POST with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866571/receive-json-post-with-php)

Answer (score 0):

Try use "file_get_contents":

```php
        $entityBody = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
        $data = isset($_POST['mainField']) ? $_POST : $entityBody;
```